# How to execute Sendkeys efficiently

Tags: excel, vba

I use Sendkeys (Excel VBA) to automate the modification of some pdf files.

In short, I open the pdf file with Acrobat by Shell command, and put wait statement like Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1")) between Sendkeys to ensure the previous Sendkeys has been processed completely.

My question is: in general, 1 second is sufficient but sometimes it does not work.
Of course, I can change the wait time to 2 seconds. But the execution time will increase significantly.

Is there any way to check the state of Acrobat and efficiently execute Sendkeys?

Comment: Yes, not using the SendKeys. Use the .dll to automate it.

Comment: You're treading dangerous waters with SendKeys, it's a very risky method to use at the best of times and should be avoided if at all possible. If you have a library/dll that allows you to check the state of Acrobat Reader then chances are you're already in a position where SendKeys could be replaced with something far safer.

Comment: Yes, Sendkeys is not a good solution, but it is the last one I know.  Actually, there is a text box with a web link at the bottom of every page of my pdf file.  What I want to do is to delete the link and the text box.  I can reference the Acrobat Type Library to remove the link.  But Acrobat Type Library does not have any method which can be used to delete the text box.  I tried to use regasm.exe to register pdfclown.dll which is a pdf editing tool, but failed.  Now still try to find an appropriate dll or any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Application.SendKeys "%fx", True
```

Comment: I tried Sendkeys "%fx", True and Application.Sendkeys "%fx", True.  Both have the same results.  When timing is not good, message from subsequent Sendkeys is discarded.

Comment: The "%fx" is just off the wall. I assumed you would use the code for the keys YOU want to send. Could this be the problem? Also, each SendKeys line should include one key only and the ", True" part, of course.

Comment: Thank Skuratovsky's reply.  I Know %fx is just for example.  When I said Sendkeys "%fx", True I mean Sendkeys "mykey", True.  The "True" parameter can not solve my problem.

Comment: The "...,True" only delays sending until the previous is processed. Since you are sending it to the "outside of Excel", the app has no way to know if the key got processed by the recipient application or not; as soon as the key got "accepted" by the recipient, the next key is sent. Sonds like you cannot win this battle, alas :(